# Retrieve email conversions

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

Is there a way to retrieve email conversions stored in tracking data in Marketing Cloud and put these information into a Data Extension using SQL Query?

Answer (score 1):

Using tracking data in order to export conversions. After that you can retrieve all the information you need.